# Salesforce - Make all fields read-only

Tags: validation, triggers, salesforce

I am trying to figure out the best way to make all fields in a custom object read only after a condition is met.

For example. There is a field called Status. If the status is equal to Closed, I want all fields on this custom object to be readonly i.e non editable.

What is the best way to do this? Validation rule, trigger, etc? I would really appreciate examples. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

In short: With a workflow you could change the record type, for that record type you can assign a page layout which is read only.

Comment: Supplement that with validation rule that goes more or less along the lines `PRIORVALUE(ISPICKVAL(Status, 'Closed'))` and error message "Once it's Closed, subsequent updates aren't allowed".

Answer (score 0):

1. Add a trigger to the custom object
2. Open custom object, click on the "Field Label" of one Custom Field, when it opens, create a new "Validation Rule" that checks the status and displays an error message